# what is browser's native support according to selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, browser, selenium-webdriver

While learning about selenium, I came to know that:

> Selenium 
>   Webdriver
>   makes direct calls to the 
>   browser using each browser’s native support for 
>   automation

I want to know, What is this native support? Is it "some HTML code", or "javascript code"?

Is there any good web link, where I can know that in what language or script, browsers are written in?

Comment: That line _only_ says that Selenium doesn't care what browser you try to automate, since Selenium knows how to access these browsers.

Comment: Sure @Cerbrus , I agree with you that selenium independently works with browsers, but I only wanted to know what is that thing that results in this independence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your language-binded code (for example, Java) implements WebDriver Interface which communicates with different browser drivers via HTTP commands.
Those drivers communicate **natively** (not http / JS injections / OS wrapping) with the browser.

By the way, here's lay the main difference between Selenium 2 and Selenium 3. in Selenium 2 it was the Selenium project responsibility to provide the driver for each browser and in Selenium 3 all the major browser vendors ship their own WebDriver implementations and because they know their browsers the best, it's much more stable and robust.

[image]

About the native implementations. Each browser native implementation is different and tightly couple to the way browser works!

For example, **Chrome** driver. Communication is done via special **Automation Proxy** module: [image]

And in **Internet Explorer**, it's done using **Communication APIs**:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answers is very helpful. I can say that this answer exactly points out what I was looking for.

Comment: **COM** in MS parlance usually means **Component Object Model**. Probably in the IE COM API as well (instead of *Communication API*).

Answer (score 0):

For each and every browser some automation methods are defined by the vendors like for Chrome, Firefox they have some automation support built within them and the selenium uses the same for the test automation, in addition Selenium is the core of automation and that is why each and every browser has support for Selenium, so selenium has to just call that code and then the browser will work according to it.

Comment: _"in addition Selenium is the core of automation and that is why each and every browser has support for Selenium"_ That's incorrect. Every browser has support for automation. Selenium uses that.

Comment: oopsie...my bad, but yes selenium is core of other automation tools and all, in fact rather than using other tools you can just use IDE and webdriver to complete all the required task

Comment: Can you please give me an example for "automation support built within browser"?

Answer (score -1):

I think following link gives some insight into the question.

http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Browser engine is the component of a browser, which parses HTML, CSS and XML.